# Aurelia Custom Elements Inside of Custom Elements & Sharing Variables

Tags: aurelia

How do I access & share variables between custom elements? I have the following files...

tip.html

```
<template>
    <div class="tip-container">
        <content select="tip-trigger"></content>
        <content select="tip-content"></content>
    </div>
</template>
```

tip.js

```
export class Tip {}
```

tip-trigger.html

```
<template>
    <span class="tip-trigger" click.trigger="showTip()">
        <content></content>
    </span>
</template>
```

tip-trigger.js

```
export class TipTrigger {
    showTip() {
        console.debug(this);
    }
}
```

tip-content.html

```
<template>
    <span class="tip">
        <content></content>
        <span class="tip__close  tip__close--default">×</span>
        <span class="tip__color"></span>
    </span>
</template>
```

tip-content.js

```
export class TipContent {}
```

In my `Tip` class I would like to have a variable name `visible`. When `showTip` is triggered `visible` would be set to true, which I would then use to add a class in tip-content.html. How can I share variables between these custom elements to do this?

The idea is to create an element to show tip pop-ups where any type of content can be the trigger and any type of content can be displayed when triggered. Basic example:

```
<tip>
  <tip-trigger><button>?</button></tip-trigger>
  <tip-content><div>Here is some helpful info...</div></tip-content>
</tip>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you just need to turn `Tip` into a service-like class and import it?

```
export class Tip {
    constructor() {
        this.visible = false;
    }
    show() {
        this.visible = true;  // Or whatever to show the content
    }
    hide() {
        this.visible = false;
    }
}
```

Then:

```
import {inject} from 'aurelia-framework';  
import {Tip} from './tip';

@inject(Tip)
export class TipTrigger {
    constructor(tip) {
        this.tip = tip;
    }
    showTip() {
        this.tip.show();
        // Or I suppose you could access 'visible' directly
        // but I like the implementation details a method call offers.
    }
}
```

*Disclaimer: This is untested.

Comment: That was the missing piece. Thanks!

Comment: @David M. Brown I thought it was not going to work if you add 2 tips in a view because inject is supposed to create singletons (unless you use `transient` decorator in Tip). But the fact is that [it woks](http://plnkr.co/edit/5nwPD8rkRm2jWTBtw874?p=preview). If you use a different class to control Tip view [it really behaves as a singleton](http://plnkr.co/edit/aA2YscqOaPkV5NUCiYe0?p=preview).  Curious...

Comment: I shared that concern, too. I'm still very much learning about how Aurelia and the associated stuff works.

Comment: @DaniCE +1 for the plnkr

Answer (score 2):

[Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/KP6qkvgiKAIHOZ0QUjVs?p=preview) is a solution to your problem in Plunker.

Note that the *tip-trigger* and *tip-content* elements are just replaceable parts of the template. They don't needed to be components themselves (that confused me a lot in the ["original" custom elements article](http://blog.durandal.io/2015/04/24/aurelia-custom-elements-and-content-selectors/)).

app.html:

```
<template>
  <require from="tip"></require>
  <tip>
      <tip-trigger><button>?</button></tip-trigger>
      <tip-content><div>Here is some helpful info...</div></tip-content>
  </tip>
</template>
```

tip.html:

```
<template>
    <div class="tip-container">
      <div>
         <div click.trigger="showContent()">
           <content select="tip-trigger"></content>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div show.bind="contentVisible">
        tip content:
        <content select="tip-content"></content>
      </div>
    </div> 
</template>
```

tip.js:

```
export class Tip {
  showContent(){
    this.contentVisible = !this.contentVisible;
  }
}
```

Comment: That is much simpler. Thank you!

Comment: Say I wanted to add attributes to `<tip-trigger>` or `<tip-content>`. Is that possible? If so, how would I access them? Is this where you would need to have them be components themselves? If so, that takes me back to my original problem of how to access a variable between components.

Comment: Yes, in that case you will need `tip-trigger` and `tip-content` to be components. See comments to @David M. Brown answer about communication between components.